# Webpack static website images cache busting

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, html-webpack-plugin

I'm using `webpack-html-plugin` to generate a one-page static website. I'm trying to implement cache busting for the static assets, images especially. I also have a meta tag for an open graph image, which is listed bellow.

My `webpack.config.js` looks something along the lines of this:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/init.js',
  output: {
    path: './build',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
    }, {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/images/[name].[ext]?[hash]'
    }, {
        test: /\.ejs$/,
        loader: 'ejs-loader?variable=data'
    }],
    plugins: {
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'src/index.ejs',
        inject: 'head',
        hash: true
      })
    }
  }
}
```

And the `index.ejs` file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <!-- ... -->
   <meta property="og:image" content="http://cdn/images/og.jpg"/>
   <!-- ... -->

   <link href="bundle.css?e0aad4b4f9d09a3a49dc" rel="stylesheet">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js?e0aad4b4f9d09a3a49dc">
 </head>

 <body>
   <!-- ... -->
   <img src="/images/logo.png" />
   <!-- ... -->
 </body>
```

My goal is to make webpack add hashes to my images as it's adding them for js and css. I know that in order to trigger the images loaders I would need to `require` the images in js, but my `init.js` only contains jquery plugins initialisation.

I tried looking at the following loaders to integrate with the `ejs-loader`

`html-loader` + `extract-loader` + `file-loader`

But I didn't get anywhere.
Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was so simple that I was actually overcomplicating things.
Basically what I needed to do is simply `require` the images inside ejs tags, like this:

`index.ejs`

```
<img src="<%= require('./assets/images/logo.png') %>" />
```

It seems like webpack got me used with doing simple things in a complicated way. Not this time though :)

Comment: so i still need to use a loader like file loader to hash and put the file in the build directory though, right?

Comment: Yes. That's correct. As the `file-loader` doc says, it resolves the require/import of the file and copies it in the dist dir. With some additional config you can also rename the file with hashes, like I had in my webpack config: 
`{
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/images/[name].[ext]?[hash]'
    }`

You can have the [hash] inside the file name if you'd like to, but I opted for query param just to bust the browser cache. Hope this helps